# Rust: what is different in the slice clone method?

Tags: rust, slice, borrow-checker, borrow

Coming from this code template which works:

```rust
{ 
  fn f3( _s : &String) {}

  fn f( s : &String) -> impl FnMut() {
   let s2 = s.clone();
   move || f3( &s2)
  }

  let mut f2 = f( &"123".to_string());

  f2();
}
```

If I modify the code this way:

```rust
{ 
  fn f3( _s : &[u8]) {}

  fn f( s : &[u8]) -> impl FnMut() {
   // let s2 = s.clone(); // don't work
   let s2 = Vec::from(s);
   move || f3( &s2[..])
  }

  let mut f2 = f( &vec![1u8][..]);

  f2();
}
```

I cannot use 'let s2 = s.clone();'. This brings the error message:

```
1169 |   fn f( s : &[u8]) -> impl FnMut() {
     |                       ------------ this return type evaluates to the `'static` lifetime...
1170 |    let s2 = s.clone();
     |               ^^^^^ ...but this borrow...
     |
note: ...can't outlive the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the function body at 1169:3
```

How can clone initiate a borrow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first example, `s` is a `&String`, and `String` implements `Clone`, so the `clone(&self)` method is used.

In your second example, `s` is a `&[u8]`, and `[u8]` does not implement `Clone`. So instead you are using the [blanket implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/clone/trait.Clone.html#impl-Clone-for-%26T) for `&T` where `T` is any type; that is, you are cloning the reference, not the thing being referenced. The result is another reference to the same thing, hence it is still a borrow.

The solution in this case is to use a different method than `.clone()` to create an owned copy of the slice. As you've noticed, `Vec::from` works, and gives you a `Vec<u8>`; you can also use `Box::from` to get a `Box<[u8]>`. You can't (currently) get a raw `[u8]` as a local variable, since that is an unsized type, so the use of `::from` here is because you need to choose what other type your owned copy will be.